How to detect runtime errors in Jupyter notebooks within VS Code extension?
I'm developing a VS Code extension to explain runtime errors in Jupyter notebooks (.ipynb files) to beginners using ChatGPT. The core functionality of my extension relies on detecting and collecting runtime error logs from Jupyter notebook execution within VS Code. However, I'm encountering significant difficulty in implementing this crucial feature.
Specifically, I'm struggling to find a reliable method or API within the VS Code extension framework that allows me to:
Detect when a runtime error occurs in a Jupyter notebook.
Collect the details of these runtime errors, including error messages and stack traces.
Differentiate between different types of errors (e.g., syntax errors vs. runtime errors).
I've explored various approaches, including using the vscode.workspace.onDidChangeNotebookDocument API, but none have provided the precise functionality I need. The VS Code API documentation doesn't seem to offer a clear solution for this specific use case.
This problem is critical because without accurate error detection and collection, my extension cannot fulfill its primary purpose of explaining errors to users. I'm seeking guidance on the most effective way to implement this functionality within the VS Code extension ecosystem, particularly for Jupyter notebooks.
I tried several approaches to detect and collect runtime errors:
Using vscode.workspace.onDidChangeNotebookDocument API:
Expected: To capture changes in the notebook that might indicate an error.
Result: This method detected general changes but couldn't reliably identify or capture specific runtime errors.
Exploring Jupyter-specific APIs in VS Code:
Expected: To find a dedicated method for Jupyter notebook error handling.
Result: Couldn't find a clear API specifically for this purpose in the VS Code documentation.
Attempting to intercept console output:
Expected: To capture error messages printed to the console during notebook execution.
Result: Inconsistent results; couldn't reliably distinguish between normal output and error messages.
Investigating the Jupyter kernel communication:
Expected: To directly access error information from the Jupyter kernel.
Result: Found it complex to implement and potentially outside the scope of VS Code's extension API.
In each case, I was expecting to find a reliable method to:
Detect when a runtime error occurs in a Jupyter notebook.
Access the full error details, including the error message and stack trace.
Distinguish between different types of errors (syntax vs runtime).
However, none of these approaches provided a comprehensive solution that met all these requirements. I'm still seeking a method that can accurately and consistently capture runtime errors in Jupyter notebooks within the VS Code environment.
